# Can I use an electrolytic capacitor on UCAP?

Tags: capacitor, usb, atmega

I have a small board based on the ATmega32u4, which I'm assembling. I only have electrolytic capacitors in 1uF value sitting around.

Can I use an electrolytic cap from UVCC to ground, instead of a ceramic one?

Comment: What type of electrolytic? Tantalum? Or aluminium?

Comment: @JohnHonniball: Aluminum, I belive.

Comment: Post a schematic, if it's a decoupling cap you can't use an electrolytic cap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

You can use electrolytic capacitor since UVCC (**USB Pads Internal Regulator Input supply voltage** from datasheet) is for power supply. I assume you have aluminum electrolyte capacitor. Electrolytic capacitors are polarized(unlike ceramic) so take care while installing.